# CEDET: Case insensitive completion?

Tags: emacs, cedet

I am programming in C++ using CEDET and I would like autocompletion to be case-insensitive. Is there a way to do this?
For instance, semantic will complete:

```
GL_POI => GL_POINTS
```

but not

```
gl_poi => GL_POINTS
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`case-fold` is the usual phrase to look for.

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `apropos-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `case-fold` <kbd>RET</kbd> turns up the `semantic-case-fold` variable, so I'd try that first.

You'll notice that this variable is automatically buffer-local, so you may want to set a default value, if you decide you want it enabled for all situations:

```
(set-default 'semantic-case-fold t)
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I do apropos-variable, there doesn't seem to be a variable named semantic-case-fold. I am using the latest CEDET from bzr. However, I evaluated (set-default 'semantic-case-fold t) and now it sort of works, but not too well, it leaves the completed part in uppercase and the part I wrote in lower case. i.e. gl_poi => gl_poiNT

Comment: I'm guessing that you didn't have semantic loaded at the time you ran `apropos-variable`. I don't know how you'd go about resolving that mixed-case problem, sorry.